# MYSQL: update a row without mentioning fields name

Tags: mysql, sql

I there a way to update a row without mentioning fields name ?
I mean something like:

```
UPDATE table SET VALUES(1, 'name', 'family')
```

instead of:

```
UPDATE table SET id=1, name='name', family='family'
```

**update**
I'm using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and don't want to use `REPLACE` function because `REPLACE` function will cause a record to be removed, and inserted at the end, which will cause the indexing to get broken apart, decreasing the efficiency of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do like that with mysql, as set clause indicates which columns to modify and the values they should be given

FYI: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 3):

If you specify the values in the same order as the table definition you could use

```
REPLACE INTO table VALUES(1, 'name', 'family');
```

Note that this will replace the entire row, so you must specify all the values you need!

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained why you need to do this?

Comment: I'm using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because `REPLACE` function will cause a record to be removed, and inserted at the end, which will cause the indexing to get broken apart, decreasing the efficiency of the table.

Comment: @Omid: Then you are not using `UPDATE`, you are using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Post the entire code you have, on the question, don't waste other people's time.

Comment: @ypercube `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in the second part works completely like an `UPDATE` function. Sorry dear friend.

Comment: @Omid: No, it doesn't. There is no `SET` in this case. And you can use `VALUES(column)`. Still no actual code in your question.

Comment: @ypercube using `VALUES(column)` or some other additional possibilities are not the real important issues, you don't have to waste your time here my friend and you can just say `i don't know`. Thank you.